# How was Jon Snow able to kill the White Walker in S05E08?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In "Hardhome", the eight episode of season five of *Game of Thrones*, Jon Snow battles a White Walker. As established, White Walkers can only be killed by dragonglass. But in this battle Jon Snow kills a White Walker with his sword. Does this mean that Jon Snow's sword is made of dragonglass? If not, how does he kill a White Walker?

Comment: I didn't watch this episode yet and I'm _really_ sad to read it. Please put a spoiler at least next time in your explanation. I know you can't put it in your title but you can do something at least `<SPOILER>Title</SPOILER>` ? Moderators, what is your opinion?

Comment: @SonerGönül titles shouldn't have spoilers. That is our long-standing policy.

Comment: But people should have some consideration. Coming here soon after something has been broadcast and putting a spoiler in the title and not using spoiler tags in the body is not nice, especially not since this question is likely [already answered online](http://comicbook.com/2015/06/01/game-of-thrones-what-is-jon-snows-sword-made-of-/), something that can be found [via a simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=jon+snow+white+walker+sword).

Comment: Why be sad that you read this before watching the episode? I have not seen episode 8 yet, but it is not a spoiler to know that JS killed a white walker .. is it? I still have no idea what happens in Episode 8, or how it ends .. Are any of his other team dead? What happened in Kings Landing? What about the aristocrats locked in the prison cell? How about Little Finger, or the dwarf, what happened to them in EP8? This ain't no spoiler! <shrug>

Comment: With a series that has a following this large, it's pretty much impossible to remain unspoiled and still access the Internet. I suggest watching it as it is broadcast, or living like a hermit until you have a chance to catch up ;)

Comment: @drxzcl This question likely popped up in the "hot network questions" bar on the right. I don't think it's fair to expect GoT spoilers when researching an issue on StackOverflow.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Well, the title has been repaired already, what else to complain about now. Let's get over it.

Comment: If you have a new question **Ask a new question** Please don't significantly change your question after it's answered because it makes the existing answers useless.

Comment: “As established White Walkers can only be killed by dragonglass” — I think what was established was that they can be killed by dragonglass, *not* that they can *only* be killed by dragonglass.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

His sword is from [Valyrian steel](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Valyrian_steel), which also can kill White Walkers:

> Valyrian steel is the only thing that can kill White Walkers, alongside dragonglass, although this property is not widely known, apparently, not even to the White Walkers themselves.

This has been mentioned in the books, but not in the previous episodes of the show:

> In "A Feast for Crows", Sam Tarly tells Jon about old annals claiming
>   that dragonsteel (perhaps a synonym of Valyrian steel) is lethal to
>   the Others, like dragonglass. In the show, this is confirmed when Jon
>   Snow kills a White Walker during the battle of Hardhome. In the
>   novels, however, it has not been put to test yet.

In the episode 10 of season 5:

> Jon and Sam are discussing the event described in the question  and they agree that Jon's sword
>  [Longclaw](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Longclaw) was able to
>  kill the White Walker because it's made from Valyrian steel.

Comment: Even if i didnt read the books yet, but i think you are right, and the coming episodes will   tell us wether its true or not!

Comment: This steel was forged with Dragon fire and also has mysterious magic powers bestowed by the Valyrians (who were the masters of fire) which would be the Yin to the White Walker's Yang. A Song of Ice and Fire indeed.

Comment: Also worth noting that White Walkers are immune to normal fire. That Walker in the shelter basically put out the surrounding fire. So in all likelihood, they can also be burnt & killed with Dragon fire. So "Dracarys!!!"

Comment: @Mourad That is why Jon Snow knows nothing. ;-) +1

Comment: You are right Faizan, he does not know how important his role is, only the coming episodes will show us the truth

Comment: @Mourad Of course it will. Best character so far.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I agree with you

Answer (score 10):

The other answer is a bit too definite; like the characters in the show/books, we know far too little.

The Others/White Walkers haven't been seen for eight thousand years. Most people do not believe they exist. All that we know for sure is what we have seen: normal weapons do not harm them, but dragonglass and Longclaw do.

It is too soon to say whether every Valyrian steel weapon could kill the Others. But fans do love to theorise. Maybe every Valyrian steel weapon would be able to kill them. Or maybe if Jon is the [Last Hero](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Last_hero) or [Azor Ahai](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Azor_Ahai) then it's more about him than the sword. Maybe Longclaw is, or will somehow become, [Lightbringer](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lightbringer). Maybe the direct fire of dragons will kill them.

Comment: My answer is based on the info from GoT Wikia. I think they chose the Valyrian steel explanation because it's backed up by the book information. It's also the best explanation in my personal opinion. However, you're right, it is possible that there is something specific in Jon or his sword. +1

Comment: @Hegemon The wiki is only presenting fan theories too. I think it's likely that all Valyrian steel will work against them, but just wanted to point out that we don't know enough yet :)

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I wrote 'they chose (...) explanation'. I think most people agree that it's the most likely one, still (as I wrote above) you're completely right that there can be others.

Comment: It's not just fan theory.  It's backed by the books.  While that does not make it canon (the serie is departing from the book on several points), it does have much more credibility than a fan theory.

Comment: @Taemyr The books are not explicit and have to be interpreted. In this case it's the characters themselves that are theorising! That's what I meant by fan theories.

Comment: @curiousdannii The books are explicit on the fact that otherwise credible annals indicate that dragonsteel can hurt walkers.  This is what the other answer states.

Comment: @Taemyr Yes, but as I said, it isn't confirmed that dragonsteel is Valyrian steel. Valyria did not exist then! Even if the Valyrians learned the secrets of the earlier dragonsteel somehow we have no way to know whether every Valyrian steel weapon is equipped to kill the Others. So when the other answer says "Valyrian steel is the only thing that can kill White Walkers, alongside dragonglass" I have to respond with "probably, but that is only our best working theory, not confirmed truth from the mouth of GRRM himself."

Comment: @curiousdannii Why would one Valyrian sword be able to do it, and others not? Why bother with having rare blades (according to Tyrion 200 in Westeros), who cannot be made anymore (probably because the process involves dragon fire), and not have them all have the same capacity? I don't see the point of rejecting logic. Plenty of elements will never be "confirmed"; doesn't mean they aren't be true.

Comment: @BCdotWEB What if the Other-killing magic is lost if the steel is recast, such as for Ice? What if it requires not only dragon fire but also blood magic (like Lightbringer), and not all Valyrian steel was produced in that way? Or, as I suggested in my actual answer, what if it also depends on the wielder? There are lots of possibilities which would make narrative sense. I'm not rejecting logic, I'm saying we shouldn't proclaim theories as facts.

Comment: @curiousdannii After the dialogue between Jon and Sam in the last episode it seems that the valyrian steel is the only needed 'property'.

Comment: @curiousdannii I am writing this comment just to give you a **Thumbs up** because a single upvote isn't enough. I have always had the same opinion described in your answer. So Kudros !