# How was Meera Reed able to achieve that?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Season 6 episode 5 of *Game of Thrones* we saw that Meera turns a White Walker into shards with one thrust of her trusty spear. So how was she able to replicate the same thing that was done by Jon Snow?

Is there any connection between Jon Snow and Meera or what was the significance of that scene?

Comment: also note that Jon Snow didn't kill a walker with a normal weapon either; he was using Valyrian Steel. It's highly unlikely it has anything to do with him as a person.

Comment: Valerian steel is rumored to be forged from fire itself, much like obsidian aka dragonglass. Fire magic vs ice magic.

Answer (score 24):

This is because she used a spear with [dragonglass](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonglass) head.

> Dragonglass is a common name in Westeros for the substance known as
>   obsidian, a form of volcanic glass. Along with Valyrian steel, it is
>   one of the two known substances capable of killing White Walkers.

Dragonglass is a substance that Children of the Forest use in their weapons.

> According to legend, the Children of the Forest also made use of the
>   substance. Samwell Tarly discovered, by chance, that dragonglass is
>   one of the few materials that can harm or kill Others. According to
>   legend, the Children of the Forest would provide the Night's Watch
>   with weapons made of dragonglass specifically for that purpose.

Note that we've seen a White Walker killed by dragonglass before. As stated in the citation above, it was done by Sam in Season 3 episode [Second Sons](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Sons_(episode)#Beyond_the_Wall).

[Later](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Mhysa#At_the_Wall) Sam and Gilly met Bran and his friends in Nightfort castle at the Wall. They told them about the event and Sam provided Meera with some dragonglass.
This means that she was aware of its properties and might have incorporated it into her weapons.

Alternatively, as in the [scene](https://youtu.be/Poy6h2zJCJ0?t=47) we see Meera simply picking up the spear from the ground, it might have been one of the spears belonging to the Children. In the same scene they can be seen using spears, fighting wights and attempting to kill a White Walker.

Jon killed the White Walker using a sword made of Valyrian steel. For a detailed explanation see [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34993/jon-snow-and-the-white-walker-please-explain).

Comment: Actually, the spear **didn't** belong to the Children of the Forest - or at least, I don't think it did. Samwell Tarly provided Meera with Dragonglass when they met before heading beyond the wall - I believe that Meera made the spear with that Dragonglass.

Comment: @DrRDizzle I assumed that, because we've seen the Children fighting with similar spears. I've just rewatched the scene and it's hard to say whether it was hers or not - she just picked up a spear lying on the ground. Either way I'll adjust my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: When do we see the Children of the Forest fighting with similar spears, other than their failed attempt in the scene in question?

Comment: @DrRDizzle That's what I meant. They also fight the wights with them, for example [here](https://youtu.be/Poy6h2zJCJ0?t=31).

Comment: To add to the otherwise excellent answer provided by Chanandler: you can see a child of the forest similarly attempt to kill that same white walker by using what appears to be a dragonglass spear. However the spear used was unable to pierce the armour being worn by the white walker. [![white walker child of forest](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pXGnL.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pXGnL.png) Meera's throw however hit the exposed neck of the white walker [![white walker meera](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x5yEC.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x5yEC.png)

Comment: The spear she picks up is the same one the Child used and failed with a second earlier.

Comment: @cde It doesn't seem so. This happened in front of her, while she picked up the spear that was behind her.